# Show that $f(x) = 2x^2+4$ is reducible over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I know that this question has already been asked here before, but there's just one part that I didn't get. By definition a polynomial is irreducible whenever we can write $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ and $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ is a unit. In our case we have

$f(x) = 2(x^2+2)$, but $2$ is a unit over $\mathbb{C}$, right? so why is $f(x)$ reducible? Am I using the right definition?

Comment: Can you solve $x^2+2=0$ over $\Bbb C$?

Comment: Quadratic polynomials factor if and only if they have a root in the field.

Comment: BTW, the factorization $2\cdot(x^2+2)$ shows that $f$ is also reducible over $\Bbb Z$ (where $2$ is not a unit)

Comment: Your definition is wrong. It should be that whenever you write $f=gh$, then $g$ or $h$ *must* be a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is correct: irreducible means $\it{whenever}$ we have a decomposition $f = g h$, then $g$, or $h$ is a unit.  You only showed one decomposition. But there is another one
$$2 x^2 + 4 = (2 x + i \,2\sqrt{2})(x-i \sqrt{2})$$
where neither $g$, nor $h$ is a unit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x^2+2=x^2-(i\sqrt{2})^2$$